# Finding an Attribute on a Collection

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of checkbox inputs that I'm checking to see if any are selected:

```
var qualificationTypes = $('input[id ^=QualificationTypes_][id $=__IsSelected]');

var checked = false;

qualificationTypes.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        checked = true;
    }
});
```

My solution works, but...

Is there a more compact way (one liner) to do the `each()`, particularly as I'm only interested if *at least one* checkbox is checked?

Comment: $( "input:checked" )

Comment: Not required for the answers below, but always use `prop` for `checked` and not `attr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes :

```
var checked = qualificationTypes.is(':checked');
```

If 1 checkbox is checked, it will return true.

```js
alert($('input').is(':checked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: really simplified :) +1 from me as well

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the collection for checked items.

```
var checked = qualificationTypes.filter(':checked');

if (checked.length > 0) {
    // We have checked / selected fields
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for introducing me to the `filter()` method!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the :checked selector like this

```
if ($('input[id ^=QualificationTypes_][id $=__IsSelected]:checked').length > 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works because I don't have your HTML but here is a try :

```
var checked = ($('input[id ^=QualificationTypes_][id $=__IsSelected]:checked').length > 0);
```

Give it a try and let me know if there is any changes to do